# Solving a heat equaton.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I need to solve this heat equation:

$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = A\Delta U,|\overrightarrow x | < R,t > 0 \hfill \\
   - \alpha \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \overrightarrow n }} = \beta (u - {u_0}),|\overrightarrow x | = R,t > 0 \hfill \\
  u(x,0) = {u_h},|\overrightarrow x | < R \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

where $\overrightarrow n$ is the outer normal of the ball $|\overrightarrow x|<R$.
Could anyone give some hint on solving this kind of boundary value problem? Thanks!

Comment: Spherical coordinates?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes! Thanks!